# Python - Get the items after the keywords in an SQL query

Tags: python, string

I have the following example of piece of code:

This is a flattened SQL query. In python, can I get each item after the keywords, because I need to use them as inputs to functions. For example I need the mean(age) and sum(salary) as inputs to one function, and the born> 2009 for another function? How can I apply string manipulation or some other module to get these ?

```
select mean(pd), sum(salary) 
from model
where born > 2009 
group by year
```

Comment: Not sure if I get you but are you looking for the Python equivalent of that SQL query?

Comment: I am looking to get the items from this SQL query and save them to variables, which afterwards I can use as inputs to python functions. I.e. save mean(pd), sum(salary) to a variable, save model to a variable, etc. So that afterwards I can use those variables.